Side text preview
When editing texts, specially since most monitors are more wide than tall, it would really help if the live display section is placed on the right side of the text edit box. This way, I won't have to scroll up/down every time to see how things look like.

There's a third-party add-on for this: Stack Exchange Side-By-Side Edit and Preview. Though the original author is no longer maintaining it, so it might not work on today's browsers.
